# How to run a C program in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I used to use Replit for my IDE, but I want to try Visual Studio Code (VSC) because my teacher said VSC was a great IDE to use. So I took a program I wrote a while back and put it in, but when I try to run the program, it just keeps telling me that I need to install an extension environment for C, because VSC doesn't come with one naturally. I already downloaded the C/C++ extension advised by Microsoft but it still isn't working. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Also, here is the extension id: ms-vscode.cpptools

Comment: Visual Studio Code isn't an IDE. It's a text-editor with plugins that add some IDE-like functionality.

Comment: As for your problem, have you read [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)?

Comment: Follow the links provided.  You need Visual Studio Code (your editor and IDE) *AND* you need the C/C++ Plugin (to integrate VSCode and the compiler) *AND* you *ALSO* need a C++ compiler (for example, MinGW).  Please be sure to "upvote" and "Accept" AnkitShetty04's reply below.

Comment: VSC is a good IDE, but the frustrating part is you end up having to hack `.json` files to make it work. If you haven't encountered json or have no interest in learning it, then VSC will be quite frustrating. There are step-by-step examples on the MS site on how to create a basic `tasks.json`, from there you can add as needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A text editor with plugins that add some IDE-like functionality is an IDE.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.  You're not wrong.  But I *HOPE* you're not suggesting that  Some programmer dude is wrong, either.  His recommendation to the OP ("read [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)) was absolutely spot-on. And I agree with his statement: "[VSCode] is a text-editor with plugins that add some IDE-like functionality".  VSCode is an excellent solution.  But it *ISN'T* "complete" - you almost always need to "add stuff".  A potential source of confusion that directly led to the OP's posting his question.

Comment: @paulsm4 You *always* need to add something, no matter what you start with. That's the whole point of an editor with plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide for using C++ with Visual Studio Code is located here:

- [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

If you are using the windows operating system, you can install the *Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) compiler toolset* as described here:

- [Configure VS Code for Microsoft C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)

Otherwise you should read the tutorials for the compiler you want to use:

- [Tutorials for other compilers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_tutorials)

The reason I refer to links, instead of explaining the details here, is because the answer might become outdated/obsolete. Sometimes links are better than explanations.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Download the **MinGW - Minimalist GNU for Windows** at SourceForge, link [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/).

When you download Minimalist GNU for Windows (MinGW), you can choose which packages to install. You should select the following packages:

- mingw-developer-toolkit
- mingw32-base
- mingw32-gcc-g++
- msys-base

Then click on the Installation tab on the top left and click on Apply Changes.

After installation, go to your C Drive where the MinGW is installed, and enter the folders MinGW > bin. Copy the path **C:\MinGW\bin**

Now search for environment, and enter edit environment variables for your account.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QBsg.png)

Next, double-click on **Path**, click on **New**, paste the path C:\MinGW\bin, press enter, and click OK.

Verify that it has been installed correctly by opening up Command Prompt and typing in gcc --version. It should give you the current version number.

**Step 2.** In **Visual Studio Code**, click on the Extensions tab, search and install [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) by Jun Han

**Step 3.** In the **C/C++ Configurations**. Make sure the Compiler Path has `c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe` selected.
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwGyE.png)

You can get to it by opening Command Pallet (ctrl+shift+p)
typing in C/++: Select a Configuration..
then select Edit Configurations (UI)